# Outputcache - How to not cache Master Page

Tags: c#, caching, asp-classic

We are using outputcache on a couple of our pages - 
`<%@ OutputCache Duration="48000" Location="Server" VaryByParam="*" %>`

The problem is that our master page has some dynamic controls loaded onto it that we do not want to cache. Is there any way to cache everything except the master page?

Is there any easy way to do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it better to change the way you act ? Read this https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/ You may find better way for caching

Comment: If this is ASP.NET best to change the tag because it's Classic ASP at the moment.